# Can't Create association on Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to create a "OneToMany" bidirectional association in my project but when I execute "doctrine:schema:update" nothing happens.

If I create this association directly from Sequel Pro and run the update schema command, that changes dissapear... :/

The relations is:
- One "id" from Customers Table with many "customer_id" form Control table.

Here is the Customers code:

```
<?php

namespace Ourentec\CustomersBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Customers
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Customers
{
 /* @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=100)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="lastname", type="string", length=100)
 */
private $lastname;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="address", type="text")
 */
private $address;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="phone", type="string", length=100)
 */
private $phone;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="pass", type="string", length=100)
 */
private $pass;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="tasks", type="text")
 */
private $tasks;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="string", length=100)
 */
private $status;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=100)
 */
private $email;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime")
 */
private $date;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="location", type="string", length=100)
 */
private $location;



/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Control", mappedBy="customers")
 */
private $customer_id;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->customer_id = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

And the Control code:

```
<?php

namespace Ourentec\CustomersBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Control
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Control
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="customer_id", type="integer")
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Customers", inversedBy="control")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $customerId;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer")
     */
    private $userId;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime")
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="seen", type="smallint")
     */
    private $seen;
```

I followed the documentation from this 2 websites
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html
http://librosweb.es/libro/symfony_2_x/capitulo_8/relaciones_y_asociaciones_de_entidades.html

But I don't know why it does not work..

Any idea will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

Mapping are not correct, I will try to explain how it works.

In Customers entity (you should rename it to Customer, entites names are singular)

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Control", mappedBy="customer")
 */
private $controls;
```

Mapped by option defines field name in the other entity.

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="customer_id", type="integer")
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Customers", inversedBy="controls")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $customer;
```

Same thing with inversedBy.

In Customers entity you also need to init controls var as an ArrayCollection:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->controls = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

With these mappings schema should be updated correctly.

For more info, check [doctrine docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional).

Comment: I'm glad to hear that :)